# What signal does the shell send when it's about to close

Tags: c, shell, unix, client, signals

I'm building a chat in c under unix. I have a server side and a client side.
All works great except when the client closes the shell window. 
In that case the client didn't tell the server he's going and the server thinks he is still logged in.

I want to handle the signal when the client closes the terminal by pressing the X button.
What signal does my process get? I tried to handle SIGHUP, SIGQUIT and SIGTERM but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Are you using TCP sockets? Please, add further details. You could use the fact that closing the terminal will kill Client, so, on Server Side, read function will return 0.

Comment: Are you using any form of multiplexing on the server's side? if not i would recommend using epoll. That way when you close the client(closing the socket on the clients side) epoll will handle it for you.
See this for a full example
https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/

Comment: SIGHUP is what it should get.  Maybe there's a problem with your signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can send one of the user defined signals SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 when client press X to close the terminal and capture the same in server application. For this you need to a get the information about terminal from which server receives the signal terminal from list of open terminals needs to be maintained.

more description about these signals can be found in man page of signal or [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal%207)

```
 Signal     Value     Action   Comment
 ---------------------------------------------------
 SIGUSR1   30,10,16    Term    User-defined signal 1
 SIGUSR2   31,12,17    Term    User-defined signal 2
 SIGTSTP   18,20,24    Stop    Stop typed at tty
```